Exceptions related to reflection when trying to use com.google.gson java code in IOS with J2Objc
I have an app generated using J2Objc 2.8 and it runs without problems both in the simulator and in real devices.
But i've recently added the com.google.gson source code to the app and, though the app builds without errors, when it runs and calls the com.google.gson.Gson.toJson method throws this exception:
com.google.j2objc.ReflectionStrippedError: JavaLangReflectGenericDeclaration: Reflection is unavailable. Fix this by avoiding reflection or building without --strip-reflection.
at 0x00000001053f56d7 java.lang.Class.GetMetadataOrFail() + 20
at 0x00000001053f5ccf java.lang.Class.getMethod:parameterTypes:() + 26
at 0x0000000104cf5b99 com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper$RecordSupportedHelper.() + 116
at 0x0000000104cf59e7 com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.() + 50
at 0x0000000104cf54a9 com.google.gson.internal.reflect.ReflectionHelper.isAnonymousOrNonStaticLocal() + 119
at 0x0000000104d06f86 com.google.gson.internal.Excluder.excludeClass() + 386
at 0x0000000104d068be com.google.gson.internal.Excluder.create() + 130
at 0x0000000104da94dc com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter() + 596
at 0x0000000104da9fd9 com.google.gson.Gson.toJson() + 103
at 0x0000000104da9f03 com.google.gson.Gson.toJson() + 142
at 0x0000000104da9d61 com.google.gson.Gson.toJson() + 82
at 0x0000000104da9ca0 com.google.gson.Gson.toJson() + 81
I don't understand why, because I don't use the --strip-reflection option. This is how I generate the code:
../j2objc -use-arc -d build_output -sourcepath ./src/main/java $(find src/main/java -name '*.java')
I've tried the command line option --reflection:all but the result is the same.
And I also tried with option --no-strip-reflection, but j2objc fails with this message: "j2objc: invalid flag: --no-strip-reflection".
All these options are from J2Objc reference https://developers.google.com/j2objc/reference/j2objc.
Any suggestion about how to use com.google.gson with J2Objc will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Unfortunately, 2.8 is an ancient release, and we don't distribute binary releases any more because we outgrew GitHub's (reasonable) storage limits. We instead recommend that you work from the latest source, building using the https://developers.google.com/j2objc/guides/building-j2objc doc. I can't dump the 2.8 version of java.lang.reflect.GenericDeclaration to see if it has reflection metadata, but after you build from source, it's easy to inspect GenericDeclaration.m.
